# Post text file upload to WCF Data Service from JQuery

Tags: wcf, service, text-files

[Uploading and downloading files using wcf data services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042025/uploading-and-downloading-files-using-wcf-data-services)

How can we implement this on the wcf data service end and using html+jquery as client?